How to Match HTML Fields with Specific Cases Using Regex in C#
I need help with creating a regex pattern in C# to match and extract fields from an HTML string that can be in one of three different cases:

The field is empty.
The field contains the info I need.
The field contains the info I need, but it includes the word "&quot;"

Specifically, I want to match the fields inside the adr, gadr, tel, and spec categories in my HTML code. Here is an example of the HTML:
adr=" Hello World, p.k. 8600, № 2" gadr="I Love regex" tel="" wrk="Thanks \&quot;For the Help!\&quot;" spec=""

My pattern is the following:
adr="(?[^"](?:\"[^"]))" (?:gadr="(?[^"](?:\"[^"]))")? (?:tel="(?[^"])")? (?:wrk="(?[^"](?:\"[^"]))")? (?:spec="(?[^"]*)")?
I want to create a regex pattern that can:

Match fields that are empty.
Match fields that contain the required text.
Match fields that contain the text and also remove the &quot; words.


Consider using an html parser instead of a regex, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c
